# android ExpandableListView design problems

Tags: android, expandablelistview

it's possible to do this ExpandableListView and how please??!

[image]

thanks a lot

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can set custom groupindicators, we can set like this:

```
expListView.setGroupIndicator(getResources().getDrawable(
                    R.drawable.group));
```

Comment: expListView.setIndicatorBounds(mExpandableListView.getRight()- 40, expListView.getWidth());

Comment: thanks for  expListView.setIndicatorBounds(mExpandableListView.getRight()- 40, expListView.getWidth());